# How do I check in AWS if a user has two access keys and how can I find out date when one of them has been disabled?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to check in AWS if a user has two access keys, and I'd like to know when one of the keys was disabled.

I've tried:

```
import boto3
iam = boto3.client('iam')

        
  for user in iam.list_users()['Users']:
      print(user)
      res = iam.list_access_keys(UserName=user['UserName'])
      print(res)
```

But it doesn't show me the information I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running these `awscli` commands:

```bash
aws iam generate-credential-report | jq -r '.State'
```

And then

```bash
aws iam get-credential-report \
  | jq -r '.Content' \
  | base64 --decode > your_report.csv
```

This will give you the full report on your user's keys (last accessed, issued, rotated etc.) and a lot more.

Here's an overview of what's in the [report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea how I could implement this command in python so that I have access to this information?

Comment: Use boto3 and [generate_credential_report](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.generate_credential_report).

Comment: I don't find the date when was disabled.

Comment: The value is called "last_rotated". The date and time, in ISO 8601 date-time format, when the user's access key was created or last changed. If the user does not have an active access key, the value in this field is N/A (not applicable).

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to view the information using the console for all the users in a given AWS account by downloading the IAM credential report.
This report is a snapshot of your IAM users and root account, contains details about security credentials, such as whether MFA is activated, when passwords were last rotated, access key 1 / access key 2 if any.

Reference article
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-in-iam-quickly-identify-when-an-access-key-was-last-used/